# How to use DependencyProperty in ViewModel at wpf Prism

Tags: prism

I am working on WPF Prism. trying to display usercontrols(in my case, ItemTest) using itemscontorl.

I am trying to use DependencyProperty to bind the values of properties of usercontrol in itemscontrol. however, some problems have occurred.

I'm not sure how to wire UserControlView (DependencyProperty TitleProperty) and ViewModel (TitleViewModel).

InputView

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding InputItems}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                            <RowDefinition/>
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <local:ItemTest Title="{Binding title}"/>
                    </Grid>
                    
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

ItemsTestView

```
<UserControl x:Class="HMI.Modules.InputArea.Views.ItemTest"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:HMI.Modules.InputArea.Views"
             xmlns:mtest="clr-namespace:HMI.Modules.InputArea.ViewModels"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"
             >

   
    <Grid Background="Red">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Text="{Binding TitleViewModel}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

ItemsTestView.cs

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TitleProperty =
             DependencyProperty.Register("Title", typeof(string), typeof(ItemTest),
             new PropertyMetadata(null));


        public string Title
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TitleProperty); }
            set { 
                SetValue(TitleProperty, value); 
            }
        }
```

ItemTestViewModel

```
string _titleViewModel;


        public string TitleViewModel {
            get => _titleViewModel;
            set { 
                SetProperty(ref _titleViewModel, value); 
            }
        }
```

I want to display the binding value when I input the "Title" of "Itemtest" in the Main Xaml.

**current status**
[image: current]

**desired result**
[image]
thanks

Comment: Can you explain "some problems"?

Comment: In the Main module, I input "Tilte" value to the ItemTest control, but nothing happens.
Since the Datacontext of ItemsTestView is ItemTestViewModel, it seems that it cannot access the DependencyProperty defined in the code-behind.

Comment: Also, what does `{Binding title}` bind to? What do you expect from `AutoWireViewModel` here? The data context of `ItemTest` comes from `InputItems`, doesn't it?

Comment: There is nothing to expect from AutoWireViewModel . I just used it to separate the usercontrol's(ItemTestView) view and the viewmodel.

Comment: That's not what it does, it sets the data context. In your case the data context _is already set_ because you're working with a data template for items in a list. What's the definition of `InputItems` and how is it initialized? WHAT DOES `{Binding title}` BIND TO???

Comment: "inputitems" is ObservableCollection<InputItem>, InputItem  that inherits from INotifyPropertyChanged and have string parameter ("Title").
I defined it in the InputViewModel constructor.